# Token Pasting Confusion

Tags: c, macros

all

My codes like this:

```
#define TTP_ROUTE_TABLE_ENTRY_INC(table)    \
static inline void  \
ttp_route_##table_inc(void)   \
{   \
    cur_l3_##table_table_entries++;   \
}
TTP_ROUTE_TABLE_ENTRY_INC(ipv4_host)
TTP_ROUTE_TABLE_ENTRY_INC(ipv4_route)
TTP_ROUTE_TABLE_ENTRY_INC(ipv6_host)
TTP_ROUTE_TABLE_ENTRY_INC(ipv6_route)
#undef TTP_ROUTE_TABLE_ENTRY_INC
```

but gcc warning:

```
lib/ttp-route-table.c:130:1: error: redefinition of 'ttp_route_table_inc'
```

So I think GCC preprocess ##table into table, actually I want

```
TTP_ROUTE_TABLE_ENTRY_INC(ipv4_host)
```

will be translate into this:

```
static inline void  \
ttp_route_ipv4_host_inc(void)   \
{   \
    cur_l3_ipv4_host_table_entries++;   \
}
```

So I don't know what's wrong with my codes. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need another set of `#` after the argument `table`:

```
ttp_route_##table##_inc(void)
```

The same goes for other lines containing `table`.